# Execute phpmailer script only if google captcha is successfully executed

Tags: php, phpmailer, recaptcha

I need to integrate google's invisible recaptcha php script into a website with a form that works with a phpmailer script that I called sendmail.php ( form action="sendmail.php").

Is there a way to execute sendmail.php only if the recaptcha is correctly executed by the user?

I have both php scripts but I'm a newbie in php and I don't know how to combine them :(.

Here is the php script of google's captcha

```
<?php
function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '________________SECRET_KEY_______________',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

// Call the function post_captcha
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

if (!$res['success']) {
    // What happens when the reCAPTCHA is not properly set up
    echo 'reCAPTCHA error: Check to make sure your keys match the registered domain and are in the correct locations. You may also want to doublecheck your code for typos or syntax errors.';
} else {
    // If CAPTCHA is successful...

    // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
    echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';

    // Here, I suppose, I need to execute sendmail.php ( phpmailer script )

}
?>
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: You're on exactly the right track. Don't be afraid to try it!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the sendmail.php file like `require('./sendmail.php');` when captcha is successful or just copy the code and past it in the captcha success area.;

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try this method